# Can't add ppa:x2go/stable error in 14.04 LTS

Tags: ppa, x2go

This problem has kept many Ubuntu users like me from using x2go and we are forced to choose vnc or other alternatives.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
cannot add ppa: ppa:x2go/stable
please check that the ppa name or format is correct
```